# "How could you have done it?" vs "How did you manage to do it"

Tags: grammar, difference, could-modal

Could you tell me if there is any difference in meaning between the question *how could you have done it* and *how did you manage to do it*? For example:

> The match seemed impossible to pull off, but you did. **How could you have done it**?
>
> The match seemed impossible to pull off, but you did. **How did you manage to do it**?

I asked a similar question about the use of *how could have done* *something* question in expressing critisism and was told that the question *how could you have done it* sounds like a genuine question. This in turn got me thinking what is the difference between the two.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between "how could you do" and "how could have you done" when used to express critisism or annoyance?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/246150/what-is-the-difference-between-how-could-you-do-and-how-could-have-you-done)

Comment: *How was it possible for you to do it? What method did you use to do it? How did you do it? By what means were you able to do it?...*

Comment: That's irrelavent. In my previous question I was told that the question "how could have you done?" sounds like a genuine question that got me thinking what is the difference between the two questions.

Answer (score 1):

To me, "How did you manage to do it?" is simple and understandable.
 The question "How could you have done it?" doesn't make sense in context. It would fit better in this setting:
"You knew I didn't want you to go out with her! How could you have done that? How could you hurt me so?"

In a modified context like that of your original question, this might make sense:
"Unfortunately, you've lost the match. How could you have done it differently?"

Answer (score 0):

There is no real difference between the two.

As a native speaker:

> **How could you have done it?**

Sounds more rhetorical as if you are amazed by the fact the person *made a match* but do not necessarily want an actual answer.

> **How did you manage to do it?**

Sounds more genuine and is clearer that you want an answer.

Comment: See written instances of [How could you have done it?](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22How+could+you+have+done+it%22&tbs=sbd:1&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALeKk01A2xaWKrGhj1il8d9uNDdDf8tNFg:1588597667203&ei=oxOwXtvxC5DmgAaRzZ_YBw&start=10&sa=N&ved=0ahUKEwibz5O9o5rpAhUQM8AKHZHmB3sQ8NMDCIYB&biw=1487&bih=724&dpr=1.13) and [How did you manage to do it?](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22How+did+you+manage+to+do+it%22&tbs=sbd:1&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALeKk02sqX_Bi1EVQYgd_G3oDWRUJsz9Qw:1588597718627&ei=1hOwXs3QJYWU8gLzyLGgBQ&start=10&sa=N&ved=0ahUKEwjNk9bVo5rpAhUFilwKHXNkDFQQ8NMDCIgB&biw=1487&bih=724&dpr=1.13)...

Comment: ...(which are about equal). The ***much more common*** "rhetorical question" version is *How could you **do** it?*, regardless of ***when*** you did the "shocking" thing.

Comment: Hi Danill. I'm afraid the terms you gave Ngram were incomplete, so its results aren't relevant to the question. We DO say *have done it* a great deal, but *how could you have done it* is rarer. Unfortunately there's a 5-word maximum at Ngram, so I don't think it can help us here.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian thanks for the point, I removed the Ngram

Comment: @Daniil Wow! That was quick! :-)

Comment: @OldBrixtonian :)